# Create a common database connection for a set of systems connected on the same network

Tags: java, sql, datasource, connection-pooling

I want the systems using this code to connect to a common database that is present in a single system in this case @10.145.10.100. I want the source files to be in the local system and still be able to run the various applications from a single SQL in the system @10.145.10.100. As of now the systems run on the server present in the local systems because as I said earlier I want the projects using this connection to have their source files in their own machines. If the same can be accomplished by running it in one tomcat server then those solutions are also welcome. The error that is currently showing up is ***ConnectionTimedOut***

*CommonConnection.java*

```
    /**
     * Builds the URL
     */
    private void buildURL(){
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.dennis.connection.dbinfo");
        String urlNamespace = resourceBundle.getString("URL_NAMESPACE");
        String domain = resourceBundle.getString("DOMAIN");
        String port = resourceBundle.getString("PORT");
        URL = urlNamespace+domain+":"+port+"/";

    }

    /**
     * A poolable connection object is created using SUN API
     * @param dataSourceName the datasource name is passed by the coder who uses this function
     */
    public CommonConnection(String dataSourceName) {
        ResourceBundle.clearCache();
        ResourceBundle dbInfo = ResourceBundle.getBundle(DATABASE_INFO_PATH);
        ResourceBundle dbSchema = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle(DATABASE_SCHEMA_PATH);
        this.dataSourceName = dataSourceName;
        this.buildURL();
        DRIVER = dbInfo.getString("DRIVER");
        URL += dataSourceName;
        USERNAME = dbInfo.getString("USERNAME");
        PASSWORD = dbInfo.getString("PASSWORD");

        try {
            ds = setUp();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * sets up the datasource
     * @return the datasource
     * @throws Exception exception that occurs has to be handled instansiation, illegal access, class not found
     */
    public DataSource setUp() throws Exception{
        Class.forName(CommonConnection.DRIVER).newInstance();
        connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool();
        connectionPool.setMaxActive(10);
        ConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                CommonConnection.URL, CommonConnection.USERNAME,
                CommonConnection.PASSWORD);
        PoolableConnectionFactory pcf = new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf,
                connectionPool, null, null, false, true);
        return new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
    }


    public GenericObjectPool getConnectionPool() {
        return connectionPool;
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the dataSource for the connection
     */

    /**
     * returns the connection object from the datasource
     * 
     * @return the connection object
     */
    public Connection getJNDIConnection() {
        Connection result = null;
        try {

            if (ds != null) {
                result = this.ds.getConnection();
            } else {
                log("Failed to lookup datasource.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            log("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The properties that are referenced are shown below

*dbinfo.properties*

```
DRIVER =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DATASOURCE_CONTEXT =java:comp/env/jdbc/
URL_NAMESPACE =jdbc:mysql://
DOMAIN=10.145.10.100
PORT=3306
USERNAME =root
PASSWORD =admin
```

*THe context file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/bank_admin_user" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root" 
        password="admin" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://10.145.10.100:3306/bank_admin_user;create=true" />
</Context>
```

Comment: try to add your library inside WEB-INF/lib folder if u are using Eclipse

Comment: I know you put it in italics, but are you *sure* that mysql-connector-java-???-bin.jar is in Tomcat's `lib/` folder? Have you restarted Tomcat since you installed it there? Are you *sure* that you are reading your properties file correctly? Have you printed out the name of the driver you are trying to load?

Comment: I have updated the question Jason. And yes, the jar file wasn't added but having added it now I get the exception saying that "the connection has timed out".

Comment: Could that be because of access restrictions? I am using MySQL 5.1.36-community

Answer (score 0):

If the database server has a firewall, a connection from other machine might be rejected.

Comment: Quite possibly that or the access rights to the server. Either way I won't be able to tell because I don't have access to change the sql server properties and test it out. But thank you for your response.